# what is INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL permission?

Tags: permissions

In my project.. I needed to make multiuser enviroment.
So I declared INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL permission.

Then I also found INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS permission.
INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL and INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS, what is the difference?

what is INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL permission?

Comment: I can't find  INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL.

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate since it is not mentioned in the link above.